# Finding function $\mathrm{supp}(\psi): \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\mathrm{supp(\psi)} = U$?

Tags: general-topology

As Function I've chosen

$$\psi(x) = \begin{cases}
0&\text{if}\:\vert x\vert\geq1\\\\
\exp\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2-1}\right)&\text{if}\:\vert x\vert <1
\end{cases}$$

because I think it's fulfilling the condition $\mathrm{supp}(\psi(x)) = U$ where
$U = [-1,1]$ and $\mathrm{supp}(\psi(x)) = \overline{\{x\in U, \psi(x)>0\}}$ and $\psi \in C^\infty$

Apparently it doesn't seem to have this behaviour (As I've been told)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "apparently it doesn't seem to have this behavior"? How did you come to the conclusion that your function does not fulfil the requirement?

Comment: the functions doesn't seem to have the property $supp(\psi(x)) = U$ At least that's what the tutor told me.

Comment: Your tutor is wrong; this function satisfies the condition.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some other feature they wanted other than a function whose support is $[-1,1]$?   Because the support is just the closure of the places where the function is nonzero,  so that's a pretty basic property to have a function...any piecewise function that is nonzero in $[-1,1]$ and 0 outside will do.  (actually the values on -1,1 don't matter)

Comment: Also $\psi \in C^{\infty}$. I guess this is also true. Maybe he's wrong then.

Comment: Oh hang on, if you differentiate the function its support no longer is part of U... But otherwise it has never been told its derivative also should fulfil the condition $supp(\psi) = U$

Comment: Probably the real problem is, that $-1$ and $1$ don't belong to $\mathrm{supp}(\psi)$ because the function gets 0 exactly at this point, right?

Comment: This taken care of by the closure, you get $\operatorname{supp}(\psi)=\overline{(-1,1)}=[-1,1]$. However your function is not in $C^\infty$.